# How to calculate the average in linux?

Tags: linux, awk

How to calculate the average in linux?

```
I have a file like this:
ID          Math       Sci        Eng         Average
230          70         -          50
123          50         50         60
223          -          80         90
```

I need the output like this:

```
ID          Math       Sci        Eng         Average
230          70         -          50            60
123          50         50         60            53.33
223          -          80         90            85
```

I am using this code, but I am only able to get the total:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {tot+=$i}; avg=tot/cnt[i]; print $1 "\t" avg}'
```

I calculated total using the above; and thought that I will be able to count the no. but its giving me an error .. Please help me, I am new to this field .. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to include error message as well?

Comment: awk? you'd be better off using Ruby or Perl

Comment: `perl -lpe 'if(/^\d/){local($a,@_,$s,$")=split/\s+/;map{$s+=$_;++$"if/\d/}@_;$_.="\t".$s/$"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ {
    tot = 0; 
    count = 0; 
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        to += $i; 
        if($i + 0 == $i){
           count++;
        }
    }
    avg = tot/count; 
    print $0,avg; 
}'
```

Might be better to put it into a script.

Comment: `tot/(NF - 1)` produces the wrong average for students who have not taken all three classes (e.g., ID #230).  You'll need to count the numberish scores and divide by that.

Comment: Can you please tel me how to count for each row?

Answer (score 1):

#### `AWK` Script:

```
awk '
/^[0-9]/{
            total=0;
            count=0;
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
            {
                total=total+$i; 
                if($i!="-") 
                {
                    count++;
                }
             }
            print $0"\t\t" total/count
         }
!/[0-9]/{
            print $0;
            next
         }' avg.txt
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat avg.txt 
ID          Math       Sci        Eng     Average
230          70         -          50
123          50         50         60
223          -          80         90

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
/^[0-9]/{
            total=0;
            count=0;
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
            {
                total=total+$i; 
                if($i!="-") 
                {
                    count++;
                }
             }
            print $0"\t\t" total/count
         }
!/[0-9]/{
            print $0;
            next
         }' avg.txt 
ID          Math       Sci        Eng     Average
230          70         -          50       60
123          50         50         60       53.3333
223          -          80         90       85
```

Answer (score 0):

in Ruby:

```
filename = '/tmp/input'
outfile = '/tmp/output'

first = true
out = File.open(outfile, 'w')
File.readlines( filename ).each do |line|
  arr = line.split
  if first
    out.puts line
    first = false
  else
    sum = 0
    arr[1..3].each{|x| sum += x.to_i }
    denom = arr[1..3].count{|x| x =~ /\d+/ }
    avg = sum  /  denom.to_f
    arr << avg

    out.puts arr.join(' '*10)
  end
end
out.close
```